# Running a function for each element

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

I am using the Peity js plugin to create donut charts on my page. I am trying to animate the chart for each of the `.foo` elements:

```
<span class="foo" data-value="10"></span>

$('.foo').each(function () {

    var updateChart = $(this).peity('donut');
    var text = "";
    var i = 0;

    function myLoop() {
        setTimeout(function () {

            text = i + "/12";

            updateChart.text(text)
                .change()

            i = i + 0.2;

            var maxValue = $(this).data("value");
            if (i <= maxValue) myLoop();

        }, 0.5)
    }
    myLoop();
});
```

However it won't work for some reason with no errors in console. If I remove the `$('.foo').each(function () { ... }` part (and all "this" instances) the code will work. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: take that function outside of the loop and pass as an argument the reference of $(this). Also, your script should be either inside <script> tags or in a js file, I see it under some html, but I assume you know that, right?

Comment: `this` inside timeout callback isn't referring to the element you think it is

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/w39jeeyq/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the context inside the timer handler, the easiest fix here is to use a closure variable

```
$('.foo').each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);

    var updateChart = $this.peity('donut');
    var text = "";
    var i = 0;

    function myLoop() {
        setTimeout(function () {

            text = i + "/12";

            updateChart.text(text)
                .change()

            i = i + 0.2;

            var maxValue = $this.data("value");
            if (i <= maxValue) myLoop();

        }, 0.5)
    }
    myLoop();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

When the timeout callback is executed, the `this` context refer to window, because you are actually calling `window.setTimeout` method.

Try this:

```
$('.foo').each(function () {

    var updateChart = $(this).peity('donut');
    var text = "";
    var i = 0;

    function myLoop() {
        setTimeout($.proxy(function () {
            text = i + "/12";
            updateChart.text(text)
                .change()
            i = i + 0.2;
            var maxValue = $(this).data("value");
            if (i <= maxValue) myLoop();
        },this), 0.5)
    }
    myLoop();
});
```

Comment: Hi, it is actually 0.5 for smooth animation and I am getting en error "myLoop is undefined". This solution actually worked: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/w39jeeyq/1/

Comment: this one works too, but it's actually better to store the result of `$(this)` as a variable. I used proxy to show the problem with the `this` context